I did not have advanced calculus and statistics in my undergraduate (B.com (hons)), do I still qualify to apply for Econ PhD in US universities?
My undergraduate was in B.com (Hons) from the University of Delhi, India and later, my MSc in Public Policy from the University College London (UCL). In my undergraduate, I took courses like Business Mathematics, Introductory Microeconomics, Financial Accounting, Cost Accounting, Management Accounting, Fundamentals of Investments and Financial Management which were essentially applied statistics and math. Later in my master's, I had modules in applied econometrics and statistics through modules such as Introduction to Quantitative Methods (using R) and Causal Inference, which I also used in my thesis. Will all these qualify as undergraduate requirements needed to apply for PhD in Economics/Management/Public Policy/Political Economy at the schools I am aiming for namely, Harvard (Kennedy), UPenn (Wharton), MIT (Sloan), Stanford (GSB) and UChicago (Harris)? Can I make the profile better through a Pre-Doc, RAship and a good GRE score?

You are aiming awfully high for someone with holes in their background. If you cast a wider net your chances will improve dramatically. There are around 80 schools in the US that would serve you well. I think that getting rejected by one place is correlated with getting rejected by similar places. OTOH, it isn't uncommon in the US for students to have to make up a course or two.

Do you think having a pre-doc would make chances better at these places? I am willing to spend a few years working in research before applying for a PhD?

Those places are extremely competitive. I can't say what an alternate path would bring. There are good advisors at lots of places.
